# React: Conditional className is not updated in DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, antd

When conditions changes (location) react doesn't update the classname in dom, although it looks changed in react developer tools. Simplified code is something like this:

```js
      <Menu>
        {appRoutes.map(route => {
          console.log(
            pathname,
            route.path,
            pathname === route.path,
            pathname === route.path ? 'ant-menu-item-selected' : '',
          );
          return (
            <Menu.Item
              key={route.name}
              className={pathname === route.path ? 'ant-menu-item-selected' : ''}
              onClick={() => {
                setOpenKeys([getKey(route.name, index)]);
                if (app.mobile) app.toggleMobileDrawer();
              }}
            >
              <Link to={route.path}>
                <span>
                  <span className="mr-auto">{capitalize(route.name)}</span>
                </span>
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
          );
        })}
      </Menu>
```

pathname variable is from location. I use useLocation hook from react router so when location changes, component re-renders properly. console.log prints all vars as it should be. Further, when I check react developer tool, classname looks as it should be:

[image]

But when checking the elements in developer tools, class is not updated for the same element in dom:

[image]

When I refresh the page (not changing the location), it renders properly, and class name is removed from dom. So how can I force react to update the classname in dom?

Using react 16.13.1, antd components.

Comment: Maybe it's a better way to use `selectedKeys` from [Antd Menu](https://2x.ant.design/components/menu/#Menu) together with Routers `useLocation` hook to select the current menu item depending on the route?

Comment: hi @zerocewl, i did try that too, didn't work. funny thing is, component re-renders, className is attached, selectedKeys set properly, component shows that new className is assigned to the component, but in dom elements that component has still having the old classnames. i think it's kinda bug in react maybe. I should better put a working example in codesandbox to present properly.

Comment: Hm ok, the `selectedKeys` variant works nice for me. A CodeSandbox or Stackblitz example is always the best choice to shown and solve a code based problem =)

Comment: Maybe this ant-design github post / thread makes sense to you https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/6576#issuecomment-384428828

Comment: thx, sorry when you suggested selectedKeys in the first comment, i somehow understood as openKeys, as I use openKeys as well. Now I use selectedKeys and everything works fine. Thank you! Would you care to post the answer, so I can select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the `selectedKeys` property from [Antd Menu](https://ant.design/components/menu/#Menu) and set this to your current route path value.

> selectedKeys: Array with the keys of currently selected menu items

The menu may look like this:

```
                <Menu
                    activeKey={props.currentPath}
                    mode="inline"
                    selectedKeys={props.currentPath}
                    style={{ height: "100%", borderRight: 0 }}
                >
```

Additional examples can be found in antd's github thread for >[how to use sider with react-router links](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/6576#issuecomment-384428828)<.